# Comparing two string literals

Tags: java, string, literals

while comparing to strings we can do using `==` or `.equals()`

In `==` we know that it checks for references but in `.equals()` it checks for contents.

So suppose if there are 2 strings say

String s="SO";
String s1="SO";

so in this case `s1==s` and `s.equals(s1)` both will give true.

But [here](http://ideone.com/gy2UNj) it gives me false

So what I assume is `+` is high priority than `==`

so in this case

```
System.out.println(""+s1==s);
```

it will be  splitted like `(""+s1)==s` and now ""+s1 will be a new String and hence the new String will never be equal to `s` so its printing false

I am just interested to know whether I thought is right or not

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The link you provided is about final strings,My code does not have final

Comment: The answers still stand. Just read them. And read the question carefully, don't look at the title.

Comment: You could fix it by doing `System.out.println((""+s1).intern()==s)`

Comment: @rocking - Look at the answers to that question :)

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Sorry I am not aware of intern() but I can google what it is.Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Your assumption about the order of operations can basically be proved to be correct. Otherwise it would print true.

Comment: According to JLS Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct. Regarding the intern method, the java docs say: "Returns a canonical representation for the string object. A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String. When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned."

Comment: @Radiodef This is what I wanted to know whether my assumption is right or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""+s1` creates a new String Object on the heap (since it is not declared as `final`). So, the references will not be same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,As far as I know if We are making `final` then we can not change the content.Does final also means that reference is also not changed

Comment: @rocking - Immutable means you cannot change the content.. final (for primitives) means you cannot change the value.. final (for objects) means you cannot reassign the reference to point to some other object.

Comment: are content and value not the same thing?

Comment: Well I asked in my question is whether my assumption is right or not.What do you think?

Comment: now ""+s1 will be a new String and hence the new String will never be equal to s so its printing false. Yes, you are right..

Comment: Here ""+s1 means single space will added to the String s1 so it's not equal to the another String s

Comment: @Prabha - No. "" is empty string. and its different from " ". (a space). ""+s1 will be created on the heap, So, s1 and ""+s1 will be different.

Comment: @WhoAmI Empty String will added to s1 right.That's why s1 will created in heap. So concatenation happen hear. thank you

Comment: @Prabha - Yes.. you are right. :)